# Jupyter Noterbook error

Tags: python, jupyter

I just cannot use jupyter notebook. I have updated to the most recent version by      ananota, and it still does not work.
The error message is listed below:

```
C:\Users\willian>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 3, in <module>
import notebook.notebookapp
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 40, in   <module>
ioloop.install()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 207, in install
from tornado import ioloop
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 47, in <module>
from tornado.concurrent import TracebackFuture, is_future
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 34, in <module>
from tornado.util import raise_exc_info, ArgReplacer, is_finalizing
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_finalizing'
```

Comment: Install tornado package from pip

Comment: pip install tornado

Answer (score 1):

From your error it looks like the tornado package is not installed in your environment. Installing tornado with the command below should fix your problem.

```
pip install tornado
```